# Filters on Weka

Tags: java, api, filtering, weka

I need to generate a filter in Java using the Weka API that will read in files and trigger an alert if a file contains a word from a predefined list. I am just beginning Weka so am not entirely sure how this would work in weka, please help :) I can't find any tutorials which are for beginners

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to begin with Weka API can be found in [this site](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code).

When I need to build some kind of filter, I subclass BufferedReader (java.io.BufferedReader) and override some of its methods. Weka also has some interfaces and classes that can do most of the job (like selecting only some desired attributes or normalizing data). Look inside that link to gain more knowledge about it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are a beginner, the first thing you should learn is to properly use weka in your Java code. The following website will be helpful: [Wekawiki](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code)